# How To Create UI Tests For SwiftUI Dynamic VStack Items?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to do the UI Test for the SwiftUI code, the screen looks like this. I need to tap on the first or second arrow.
The list is a dynamic list.

[image]

Here is the source code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DemoSwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isNavigate = false
    @ObservedObject var demoViewModel = DemoViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing:5) {
                        Text("Showing 30 Demos for all").font(.footnote)
                        Spacer()
                        NavigationLink(destination: DemoFilterSwiftUIView().environmentObject(demoViewModel),
                                       label: {
                                        Text("FILTER")
                                            .font(.footnote)
                                       })
                    }.padding()
                    VStack(spacing: 5) {
                        ForEach(self.demoViewModel.demos, id: \.id) {
                            demoItem in
                            Button(action: {
                                print("list of Demos: \(demoItem)")
                            }, label: {
                               // DemoSectionView(demo: demoItem)
                            }).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }.environmentObject(demoViewModel)
                        Spacer()
                        if self.isNavigate == true {
          
                        }
                    }.padding(5)
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {self.demoViewModel.loadDemos()}
    }
    
    
}
```